# How to add my website to AOL.com?

Tags: seo

I have added my blog to Google console and Bing webmasters. I don't know how to add it to AOL. How to add my site to AOL.com?

Answer (score 5):

AOL Search has been powered by Bing since 2016.  See [AOL Search Now Fully Powered By Bing - Search Engine Round Table](https://www.seroundtable.com/aol-search-powered-by-bing-21426.html).

Since you have already added your site to Bing, it is automatically on AOL as well.  You don't need to do anything further to get your site to appear in the AOL search results.

Bing is similarly powering the Yahoo search results, so you don't need to do anything special to get your site included there either.